# How to create JNI module using CMakeList under Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I found in the official android documentation, there's a `CMake` tutorial, but it doesn't tell how to compile the module into `so` libs(especially into `armeabi/armeabi-v7a`).

And there's a line in the doc:

> However, if you are creating a new native library, you should use CMake.

Since they have a documentation introduce CMakeList.txt, I assume there's a way to use CMake instead of NDK, or use CMake behind NDK.

I've searched for a while, but there's only a `android-cmake` 2/3 years ago, and not so easy to understand.

Can anyone help to provide a official documentation link or if there's a tutorial, it would be better, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Docs are here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html

They explain how to use CMake for the NDK via Android Studio.